# Android align textview to textview

Tags: android, textview

there is code below. I need align textview to textview. The firsts one with id:test1 is very long with many lines and the second textview should be align to the first one test1 to the end of it. Any help?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="VERY LONG STRING HERE"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: align mean start test2 when test1 is finished. One next one

Comment: Why dont you use relative layout with test2 textview align to test1 textview with android:layout_toRightOf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make them expand to touch.

Use `layout_weight` on both.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="VERY LONG STRING HERE"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`layout_width` of `0dp` with `layout_weight` of `0.5` (out of 1) means "i do not provide a width, expand it until it reaches 50%.